# take pointer to last node of linked list with function

Tags: c, pointers

```
void go_last(bn_ptr current)
{

   bn_ptr ptr=current;

   while(ptr->next!=NULL)
   {
    ptr=ptr->next;
   }

}
```

I have linked list and 'head' pointer hold it from head,I defined new pointer and equalized it with 'head' and I only want to take 'current' pointer to last node of my linked list but my function is not working

```
struct binumber
{
    int number;
    struct binumber *next;
};

typedef struct binumber binumber;
typedef struct binumber *bn_ptr;

......

int main()
{


.
.
.
bn_ptr current1=head;
go_last(current1);//not working
.
.
.


}
```

T tried it with different function which return pointer but it didn't..

Comment: Are you getting any error? Or are you getting unexpected output?

Comment: Give the initialization code of your list.

Comment: There is no error ,I tried to see function works or not by writing  printf("current1 :%d ",current1->number);

Comment: IMHO your function is working pretty well (it goes to the last node of the list) — you just have not defined *what exactly you expect* from it. because simple 'going to the last node' apparently is *not* what you need.

Comment: thank you for your helps ... – user3121023 I tried it with your answer and it  worked,I am grateful with you...

Answer (score 1):

I hope that, you're familiar with the concepts of call by value and call by reference.
When you pass `current1` as argument to the function, another variable will be created locally, which will be having same pointer value as `current1`. And then you're modifying local pointer, which will not be reflected in calling function.

Answer (score 0):

With this function you don't make change to `current1` , as you pass be value , a copy of it is created and changes are made to it .In that case you should `return` that pointer from function and assign it to `current1`.

Second way , is to pass `&current1` as argument to function so that changes are made at value at that address and is maintained in calling function also.

Answer (score 0):

To check the last node you either need to pass `current1` as a double pointer or return the last node pointer from the function.

**Option 1:** Returning the last node from the function

```
bn_ptr go_last(bn_ptr current)
{

   bn_ptr ptr=current;

   while(ptr->next!=NULL)
   {
    ptr=ptr->next;
   }
   return ptr;
}
```

..

```
bn_ptr current1=head;
current1 = go_last(current1);
```

**Option 2:** Changing `current1` in the function itself by passing it as a reference

```
void go_last(bn_ptr* current)
{



   while((*current)->next!=NULL)
   {
    *current=(*current)->next;
   }

}
```

..

```
bn_ptr current1=head;
go_last(&current1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bn_ptr go_last(bn_ptr current)
{
   bn_ptr ptr=current;

   while(ptr->next!=NULL)
   {
    ptr=ptr->next;
   }

   return ptr;
}
```

Then in main

```
bn_ptr current1=head;
last_node = go_last(current1);//not working
```

Now last_node is your linked list's last node.